# Can gitolite manage git commit-msg hook?

Tags: git, commit, gitolite

I have been trying to find a way to make gitolite manage and propagate the git commit-msg hook to a specific repo but I have not been successful. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A [git commit-msg hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Client-Side-Hooks) is a **client-side hook**.

gitolite deals with the authorization validation on the **server side**.
As such, it has no vocation to manage a lcient-side hook such as `commit-msg`.

[The hooks that you can add in gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/gitolite.html#cb-hooks) are **update hooks** (a [server side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#Server-Side-Hooks)), or a post-receive hooks. Any client-side hook would be ignored (as in never triggered)

Comment: Thanks...I will create this hook and save it inside the repo. Then create a symlink to this hook in the /.git/hooks folder on the client machine. Any other idea?

Comment: @FabricioTobar "I will create this hook": if you are referring to an update hook, then yes, gitolite will propagate it on the git repos managed on the server side. But this differs from commit-msg hook.